# How to auto-generate unique random-looking numbers?

Tags: postgresql, random

Currently I'm passing one value to my database, it's a random and unique 10-digit number.

Is there a way I could generate this number directly in my database each time a new row is created?

It looks something like this

```
id_Primarykey  Name  random number  
1              x     1231233592  
2              Y     5234234837  
3              Z     3453450394
```

Said number has to be unique, 10 digits, and random (non-sequential).

Comment: `SELECT FLOOR(RANDOM() * 10000000000);`

Comment: I'm doing something similar in my code. I want to do it directly in the database.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean exactly by ` I want to do it directly in the database.`? p.s. welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 1):

### Getting unique random looking numbers in a given interval

If you can install C code into your database, the [`permuteseq`](https://github.com/dverite/permuteseq) extension provides a ready-to-use solution to this problem. It encrypts consecutive numbers with [format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) techniques to get both the non-guessability, the unicity (it's collision-free), and the confinment in a given output range.

To auto-assign the values on insertion, the simplest way  is to set the column's DEFAULT clause.

### Example

```
CREATE EXTENSION permuteseq;

CREATE SEQUENCE seqname MAXVALUE 9999999999; -- 10 digits

CREATE TABLE example(
 id serial,
 col text,
 random_number bigint default
     permute_nextval('seqname'::regclass, 8784354463) -- or any random number
);

INSERT INTO example(id,col) VALUES(1, 'foo');
INSERT INTO example(id,col) VALUES(2, 'bar');
INSERT INTO example(id,col) VALUES(3, 'baz');


SELECT * FROM example;

 id | col | random_number 
----+-----+---------------
  1 | foo |    9737615019
  2 | bar |    7519592769
  3 | baz |    8112392939
```